# Ember DjangoRESTAdapter data not loading

Tags: django, ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty new to Ember so hopefully I'm just doing something stupid, but I've been running into a lot of random issues with data not displaying properly and I now see in the Ember Debugger that my data does not exist until I hit a specific model data endpoint. For instance, I have a template to display all products, here's the route:

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('product');
    }
});
```

the controller:

```
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'product'
});
```

the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="products">
    <div class="row">
        {{#each}}
            {{name}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Hitting the endpoint '/products' displays nothing initially, but if I go to '/products/1' I can see the product data in the view (and in the Ember debugger), and then if I navigate back to '/products' that particular product's data (but no other data) displays properly. So I'm super confused as to what I'm doing wrong. As the title suggests, I'm using the DjangoRESTAdapter if that helps narrow things down and here's my app.js as well

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({});
window.api_location = 'http://localhost:8000/api';


App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.DjangoRESTAdapter.extend({
    host: api_location,
    pathForType: function(type) {
        return Ember.String.underscore(type);
    }
});
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.DjangoRESTSerializer.extend({
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend();
```

Thanks in advance for any help, and let me know if other code snippets would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured this out: it's an issue with pagination. I was not aware that we had pagination set up for our Django REST Api, so instead of returning a list of objects, it was returning a result object, with the list of products buried in a 'results' attribute. So until I can convince the other devs to turn off pagination I can modify all my queries:

```
this.store.find('product', {page_size:0});
```

to override our default page size.

Edit: I'm also trying out modifying the json response on the server side rather than using the djangorestadapter with this library: https://github.com/ngenworks/rest_framework_ember . Hopefully this saves some people some digging...